# Do Cardassians appear in every episode of Deep Space 9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Does at least one Cardassian appear on-screen in every episode of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*?

Comment: I don't think there's any such appearance in "Far Beyond the Stars." I could be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

## No.

The Cardassians appear in only 71 out of Deep Space Nine's 176 episodes (40.3%).

## Episodes with Cardassians:

- Emissary
- Past Prologue
- Duet
- The Homecoming
- The Circle
- Cardassians
- Necessary Evil
- Playing God
- Profit and Loss
- The Maquis, Part I
- The Maquis, Part II
- The Wire
- Crossover
- Tribunal
- The Search, Part II
- Second Skin
- Civil Defense
- Defiant
- Life Support
- Destiny
- Distant Voices
- Through the Looking Glass
- Improbable Cause
- The Die is Cast
- Explorers
- The Way of the Warrior
- Indiscretion
- Our Man Bashir
- Return to Grace
- Shattered Mirror
- For the Cause
- Body Parts
- Broken Link
- Apocalypse Rising
- Trials and Tribble-ations
- Things Past
- The Darkness and the Light
- In Purgatory's Shadow
- By Inferno's Light
- Ties of Blood and Water
- Empok Nor
- Call to Arms
- A Time to Stand
- Rocks and Shoals
- Sons and Daughters
- Behind the Lines
- Favor the Bold
- Sacrifice of Angels
- Statistical Probabilities
- Waltz
- Change of Heart
- Wrongs Darker Than Death or Night
- Inquisition
- In the Pale Moonlight
- Tears of the Prophets
- Image in the Sand
- Shadows and Symbols
- Afterimage
- Treachery, Faith and the Great River
- Covenant
- The Emperor's New Cloak
- Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges
- Penumbra
- 'Til Death Do Us Part
- Strange Bedfellows
- The Changing Face of Evil
- When It Rains...
- Tacking Into the Wind
- Extreme Measures
- The Dogs of War
- What You Leave Behind

## Episodes without Cardassians:

- A Man Alone
- Babel
- Captive Pursuit
- Q-Less
- Dax
- The Passenger
- Move Along Home
- The Nagus
- Vortex
- Battle Lines
- The Storyteller
- Progress
- If Wishes Were Horses
- The Forsaken
- Dramatis Personae
- In the Hands of the Prophets
- The Siege
- Invasive Procedures
- Melora
- Rules of Acquisition
- Second Sight
- Sanctuary
- Rivals
- The Alternate
- Armageddon Game
- Whispers
- Paradise
- Shadowplay
- Blood Oath
- The Collaborator
- The Jem'Hadar
- The Search, Part I
- The House of Quark
- Equilibrium
- The Abandoned
- Meridian
- Fascination
- Past Tense, Part I
- Past Tense, Part II
- Heart of Stone
- Prophet Motive
- Visionary
- Family Business
- Shakaar
- Facets
- The Adversary
- The Visitor
- Hippocratic Oath
- Rejoined
- Starship Down
- Little Green Men
- The Sword of Kahless
- Homefront
- Paradise Lost
- Crossfire
- Sons of Mogh
- Bar Association
- Accession
- Rules of Engagement
- Hard Time
- The Muse
- To the Death
- The Quickening
- The Ship
- Looking for par'Mach in All the Wrong Places
- Nor the Battle to the Strong
- The Assignment
- Let He Who Is Without Sin...
- The Ascent
- Rapture
- The Begotten
- For the Uniform
- Doctor Bashir, I Presume
- A Simple Investigation
- Business as Usual
- Ferengi Love Songs
- Soldiers of the Empire
- Children of Time
- Blaze of Glory
- In the Cards
- You Are Cordially Invited
- Resurrection
- The Magnificent Ferengi
- Who Mourns for Morn?
- Far Beyond the Stars
- One Little Ship
- Honor Among Thieves
- His Way
- The Reckoning
- Valiant
- Profit and Lace
- Time's Orphan
- The Sound of Her Voice
- Take Me Out to the Holosuite
- Chrysalis
- Once More Unto the Breach
- The Siege of AR-558
- It's Only a Paper Moon
- Prodigal Daughter
- Field of Fire
- Chimera
- Badda-Bing, Badda-Bang

Answer (score 5):

Emphatically not. As early as 1x04 "A Man Alone", no Cardassians appeared on-screen, and 1x06 "Captive Pursuit" had no significant mentions of them ("A Man Alone" and 1x05 "Babel" both referred to events during the Occupation). Cardassians wouldn't return to the screen until the penultimate episode of the season, 1x19 "Duet".

From the second season on, Cardassians appeared in a significant minority of episodes: 11 each in Seasons 2 and 3, 8 in Season 4, and 9 in Season 5. In Season 5 they were in 13 episodes, or exactly half (aside from the first, each season of DS9 contains 26 episodes), and in Season 7 they were in 16 episodes - meaning even as late as the final season, despite the Dominion War and Dukat plotlines, there were ten full episodes in which no Cardassians made an on-screen appearance.

With that said, Cardassians are disproportionately likely to show up in meatier episodes like season premiers and finales (they missed the first three finales, but were in the later four, and have a perfect record for season premiers), and otherwise move the plot forward; Cardassian-free episodes are more likely to be filler.